# Simple D3: turn a date object into an attractive string?

Tags: d3.js

This should be easy!

I have a JavaScript Date object and I want to turn it into an attractive string, using [D3's time functions](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting).

```
var format = d3.time.format('%e %b').parse;
console.log('graph_x', graph_x, typeof graph_x, String(graph_x), format(String(graph_x)));
```

This gives me:

```
graph_x
Tue Dec 25 2012 08:26:10 GMT+0000 (GMT) 
object
Tue Dec 25 2012 08:26:10 GMT+0000 (GMT)
null
```

How can I turn my Date object into a nice String, like "Tue 25"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[d3.time.format](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting) takes a date object and returns a string.

[format.parse](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#wiki-parse) takes a string and returns a date time object.

From the docs:

```
var format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");
format.parse("2011-01-01"); // returns a Date
format(new Date(2011, 0, 1)); // returns a string
```

Since you already have a date object, you don't need to parse it:

```
var format = d3.time.format('%e %b')
console.log(format(graph_x))
```